# How to define multiple named properties in TypeScript / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

In the 'sorting' property of the 'myItemA' object I would like to allow the definition of multiple flexibly named properties such as 'viewOrder', 'execOrder', 'persistOrder' ...
and use like this:

```
   myItemA.sorting.viewOrder = 3;
   myItemA.sorting.execOrder = 7;
   etc.
```

I am trying the definition of *ItemA* and the property *sorting* like this:

```
export abstract class ItemA {
    constructor(
      public id: string,
      public name: string,
                       // (this is may not be correct - how to correct it ?)
      public sorting?: [ {[name: string]: number} ],
      ...
```

and then create objects like this:

```
export const myItemA: ItemA = 
  {
    id: 'A1',
    name: 'A1',
                       // (compiler complains here - how to correct it ?)
    sorting: [ {'viewOrder': 0}, {'execOrder': 0}, {etc.} ],
    ...
  }
```

Comment: You can try `{ [name: string]: number; }[]` or `Array<{ [name: string]: number; }>`.

Comment: Why not just `public sorting?: { [name: string]: number; }`? That basically lets you add one to many properties onto `sorting` like your first example. `sorting: { viewOrder: 0, execOrder: 0, ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax should be like this in the constructor:

```js
public sorting?: { [name: string]: number }
```

Or:

```js
public sorting?: Record<string, number>
```

And like this when declaring the variable:

```js
export const myItemA: ItemA = {
  ...
  sorting: { 'viewOrder': 0, 'execOrder': 0 },
};
```

Comment: Yes, why did I complicate it with [] ?. Thx.